# How to force the text field to begin editing?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm using an alert view and the options are to change one of the values that are wrong so what I want to do is when the user selects which value he wants to change the text field corresponding to the value start editing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I automatically load the keyboard (iOS SDK)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759465/how-do-i-automatically-load-the-keyboard-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 13):

If you have named a UITextField givenVin, then you could try with:

```
[self.givenVin becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is the instruct the UITextField to receive focus via `becomeFirstResponder`:

```
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    [self.givenVin becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"edit ");
} else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    [self.givenVout becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2

Write this line of code in viewDidLoad

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```